# Importing images in tensorflow

Tags: python, image, filesystems, tensorflow

I'm trying to import images and convert them to tensors. All the other solutions recommend making a `filename_queue` and using `tf.reader()`, but I can't get that to work... hence, I'm just going with the basics.

I have a file called `test.jp`g in my desktop directory, and I'm running a linux environment. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg("~/Desktop/test.jpg", channels=1)
print(image)
```

As you can see, some very simple code... however it outputs

```
Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=uint8)
```

Which is telling me that it isn't reading the file correctly. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `tf.image.decode_jpeg` just constructs a graph node and adds it to an execution graph. You have to actually *evaluate* the node to *run* it and get its value as a `numpy` array. Try the following :

```
import tensorflow as tf

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file("~/Desktop/test.jpg"), channels=1)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run(image))
```

Note that the argument to `tf.image.decode_jpeg` itself should be a string  `Tensor`. Thankfully, TensorFlow has an op for reading a file into a `Tensor`, viz., `tf.read_file`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to tensorflow and forgot about the whole interactive session...